# My WP Website Shows HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, http, 500-internal-error

My website keeps showing **HTTP ERROR 500** and I'm not sure what's causing it

**[Website URL](http://igtsservice.com/)**

I tried a couple of debugging ideas like removed my .htaccess and renaming the Plugins folder, but still no luck

I check the **error_log** file and here's what i found

```
[15-Nov-2017 17:47:35 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:47:54 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:48:11 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:48:14 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:48:16 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:48:17 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:48:19 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:48:20 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:48:22 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
```

The thing is, my functions.php folder has only 234 lines of code

This is a business website, help me please

Comment: Go to `wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php ` and open it with notepad ++ or another editor. You will probably see a not closing `<?php` tag or something relative on line `280`.

Comment: @Drupalizeme I feel so stupid right now, I was checking the `functions.php` file of another directory, anyway It works now, thanks for your help

Comment: No worries(fast fix) :)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference you could use the `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` at your wp_config to easily spot errors and turn to false when you are done.

> Enabling WP_DEBUG will cause all PHP errors, notices and warnings to
>   be displayed. This is likely to modify the default behaviour of PHP
>   which only displays fatal errors and/or shows a white screen of death
>   when errors are reached.
>
> It is not recommended to use WP_DEBUG or the other debug tools on live
>   sites; they are meant for local testing and staging installs.

More info [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: after define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); where is log should be save? @Drupalizeme

Comment: @Gem WP_DEBUG_LOG is a companion to WP_DEBUG that causes all errors to also be saved to a debug.log log file inside the /wp-content/ directory. This is useful if you want to review all notices later or need to view notices generated off-screen (e.g. during an AJAX request or wp-cron run).

Comment: There is no debug.log in my /wp-content/ file, actually my website returns HTTP 500 error, how can i debug where is the error? @Drupalizeme

Comment: @Gem This is just a thread to solve one problem. If you need further help I propose to post a new question and ask there with the appropriate resources.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP ERROR 500` is an error on you code.

As see on you logs:

```
[15-Nov-2017 17:47:35 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:47:54 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:48:11 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:48:14 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:48:16 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:48:17 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:48:19 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:48:20 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
[15-Nov-2017 17:48:22 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 280
```

There is an error with your `/home/igts160XXXXX1/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php` and forced the `HTTPS ERROR 500` to display.

You didn't include the error on `line 280` on your `error.log` so i can't determine what really the error is. But there are [sample `functions.php`](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/functions-php/) everywhere on Google and the Internet.

I can help you if you can update the question with the error itself or the line of code within the function.

You could use the `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` at your `public_html` to easily spot errors and turn to false when you are done. Find that inside your `wp-config.php` file using SFTP and make sure the value is `true`.